# SQL Query contagem

Tags: sql, query

Preciso de fazer um query em que o resultado são as medalhas(ouro,prata,bronze e total(soma das 3)) obtidas por cada país em todas edições dos jogos olímpicos. Até aqui tudo bem, a query abaixo apresentada já faz isso.

O problema é que as medalhas obtidas em eventos colectivos(estafeta,etc) só podem ser contadas 1 vez, ou seja , No caso de um evento de estafeta em vez de contar 4 medalhas contar apenas 1.

É possível saber se um evento é do tipo colectivo ou individual através da tabela eventos no campo TIPOEVENTO, porque este campo ou é Individual ou Colectivo.

Penso que seja possível fazer através de uma Subquery com um count(distinct) mas não sei como.

#### Diagrama:

[image: ![Diagrama](http://imgur.com/vyhA2Mh)http://imgur.com/vyhA2Mh]

#### Resultado:

[image: ![Resultado](http://imgur.com/B69iT6q)http://imgur.com/B69iT6q]

```
    Select PAISES.NOMEPAIS, count(RESULTADOS.CLASSIFICACAO) as Total,
    Count(Case when RESULTADOS.CLASSIFICACAO = 1 then 1 end) As OURO,
    Count(Case when RESULTADOS.CLASSIFICACAO = 2 then 1 end) As PRATA,
    Count(Case when RESULTADOS.CLASSIFICACAO = 3 then 1 end) As BRONZE
    From
    RESULTADOS
          INNER JOIN PARTICIPACOES
          ON RESULTADOS.ANO = PARTICIPACOES.ANO AND RESULTADOS.ESTACAO = PARTICIPACOES.ESTACAO AND RESULTADOS.IDPARTICIPACAO = PARTICIPACOES.IDPARTICIPACAO

          INNER JOIN dbo.PAISES
          ON PARTICIPACOES.SIGLAPAIS = PAISES.SIGLAPAIS

          INNER JOIN dbo.PARTICIPANTES
          ON PARTICIPACOES.IDPARTICIPANTE = PARTICIPANTES.IDPARTICIPANTE

          INNER JOIN dbo.EDICOES
          ON PARTICIPACOES.ANO = EDICOES.ANO AND PARTICIPACOES.ESTACAO =  EDICOES.ESTACAO

          INNER JOIN dbo.ELIMINATORIAS
          ON RESULTADOS.IDEVENTO = ELIMINATORIAS.IDEVENTO AND RESULTADOS.IDELIMINATORIA = ELIMINATORIAS.IDELIMINATORIA

          group by NOMEPAIS
          order by Total desc



    SELECT DISTINCT PAISES.NOMEPAIS AS NOMEPAIS, RESULTADOS.CLASSIFICACAO,         
     EVENTOS.IDEVENTO, EVENTOS.TIPOEVENTO , PARTICIPACOES.ANO,Count(Case when      RESULTADOS.CLASSIFICACAO = 1 then 1 end) As OURO,
      Count(Case when RESULTADOS.CLASSIFICACAO = 2 then 1 end) As PRATA,
       Count(Case when RESULTADOS.CLASSIFICACAO = 3 then 1 end) As BRONZE,
   count(RESULTADOS.CLASSIFICACAO) as Total

    FROM RESULTADOS

     INNER JOIN dbo.PARTICIPACOES
    ON RESULTADOS.IDPARTICIPACAO = PARTICIPACOES.IDPARTICIPACAO

     INNER JOIN dbo.PAISES
     ON PARTICIPACOES.SIGLAPAIS = PAISES.SIGLAPAIS


     INNER JOIN dbo.EVENTOS
     ON RESULTADOS.IDEVENTO = EVENTOS.IDEVENTO

       group by RESULTADOS.CLASSIFICACAO, NOMEPAIS , EVENTOS.IDEVENTO, TIPOEVENTO,     Participacoes.ANO
```

Comment: Para quem, como eu, se pergunta o que é estafeta, é o que no Brasil chamamos de corrida de revezamento com bastão.

Comment: Quero lhe ajudar nisto. Poderia montar a estrutura básica e o insert neste site http://www.sqlfiddle.com e passar a URL, ai te ajudo a montar o SQL

Comment: O website sqlfiddle.com está extremamente lento. Caso tenha o microsoft sql server instalado, aqui deixo o backup desta base de dados, https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-jRMXMu9WvfNzkyeTk0SlBVTkU/edit

Comment: Como é uma query de contagem apenas tire os PARTICIPANTES (atletas, creio) do JOIN, seriam contadas apenas as medalhas, sejam individuais ou coletivas.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, mais ainda não é isto. Ainda conta as medalhas dos eventos colectivos individualmente, quando devia de contar apenas 1 vez.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O que acontece é que ao fazer o inner join com a tabela participantes ele associando uma linha da tabela resultado para cada linha da tabela participantes.

Se a ideia é retornar os totais de medalhas porque não colocar diretamente sem incluir todas as tabelas?

Outra coisa, para facilitar porque não colocar na tabela RESULTADOS o campo SIGLAPAIS.

```
Select A.NOMEPAIS, count(A.RESULTADO) as Total,
Count(Case when A.RESULTADO = 1 then 1 end) As OURO,
Count(Case when A.RESULTADO = 2 then 1 end) As PRATA,
Count(Case when A.RESULTADO= 3 then 1 end) As BRONZE
From
(
   SELECT DISTINCT PAISES.NOMEPAIS AS NOMEPAIS, RESULTADOS.CLASSIFICACAO AS RESULTADO, EVENTOS.IDEVENTO AS IDEVENTO, EVENTOS.TIPOEVENTO AS TIPOEVENTO, PARTICIPACOES.ANO AS ANO
   FROM RESULTADOS
   INNER JOIN dbo.PARTICIPACOES
   ON RESULTADOS.IDPARTICIPACAO = PARTICIPACOES.IDPARTICIPACAO

   INNER JOIN dbo.PAISES
   ON PARTICIPACOES.SIGLAPAIS = PAISES.SIGLAPAIS

   INNER JOIN dbo.EVENTOS
   ON RESULTADOS.IDEVENTO = EVENTOS.IDEVENTO

) AS A
group by A.NOMEPAIS
order by Total desc
```

Comment: Sim reduz os resultados obtidos, mas nos desportos colectivos continua a contar a medalha de cada participante, e não apenas uma medalha.

Comment: Por exemplo caso um país ganhe no futebol olimpico, em vez de contar 11 medalhas, devia contar apenas 1 medalha, visto ser um evento colectivo.

Comment: Mas na sua tabela RESULTADOS possui apenas a classificação do time, correto?

Comment: A tabela RESULTADOS apenas contem dados individuais. Toda a estrutura da base de dados é referente a feitos individuais.

Comment: Bom fiz uma modificação no comando, agora ele recebe os dados em modo distinct ou seja apenas uma linha diferente da outra mas acredito que você terá que modificar esse código para incluir algumas coisas na linha do select, se o idevento e o tipoevento forem iguais para vários anos por exemplo esse código vai dar erro então terá que incluir algo que diferencie o ano.

Comment: Vi onde pegaria o ano e fiz a modificação incluindo o ano, mas verifica se o código vai retornar exatamente o que você precisa.

Comment: Bem , a query não funciona visto que as colunas , NOMEPAIS, RESULTADO que estão no select são invalidas e o NOMEPAIS no group by tambem.

Comment: Adicionei uma query que ja faz QUASE aquilo que pretendo, o problema está que apresenta para cada pais todas as classifcaçoes. Falta juntar tudo.

Comment: Estranho não funcionar alegando que é invalido, porque o select interno gerou uma nova tabela (na memoria) com esses campos. por isso usei o AS. (SELECT DISTINCT PAISES.NOMEPAIS AS NOMEPAIS, RESULTADOS.CLASSIFICACAO AS RESULTADO) foi colocado dessa forma? De qualquer forma fiz uma modificação nomeado a nova tabela como A e colocando no Select, quem sabe.

Comment: Funcionou! Muito Obrigado.